# Eloquent Relationship in the same model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am using `User` model to fetch `user_type = 5`. They are associated with `user_type = 3` in `vendors` table. I want to make a relationship in `User` or `Vendor` model which could help me get `users` of type `5` along with the associated user of type `3`.

Comment: If it is 1:1, use the hasOne method in the User from the laravel documentation.

Comment: does any of your table has a foreign key to related table i.e does your vendors table has a column user_id ?

Comment: @KhanShahrukh yes and `associated_id` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data with a criteria you can use scopes, like this :

```
public function scopeMyType($query)
{
    return $query->where('user_type ',  3);
}
```

To use it :

```
$users = User::myType()->get(); 
// this will return users with type = 3
```

You can make self relationship like this:

```
class User extends \Eloquent {
    ....
    public function hasOne() {
        $children = $this->hasMany('Vendor');
   }
}
```

Comment: see I want to extend your result. This has already been implemented. Now in `Vendor`, `user_type = 3` has many `user_type = 5`. I want this to add in the relationship & query as well. I hope you got my point now.

Comment: Why not using a scope for each type? or a simple where query, like this : `User::where('user_type', 3)->with('vendor')->get()`

Comment: it gives my result for only `user_type = 3` but not for the associated `user_type = 5`